# Regarding booting Ubuntu 16.04 onto Windows 10

Tags: boot, grub2

I've run into multiple issues in trying to dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 onto Windows 10. My laptop is an Acer Aspire E15. I've tried manually partitioning space and installing Ubuntu as well as doing the easier method of just choosing "Install alongside Windows." I've had Windows on my laptop before installing Ubuntu. But after installation, no boot loader comes up that asks if I want either Windows or Ubuntu.

I'm posting this because I've read multiple articles and forums about this same issue but none of what I've read have fixed the issue. One such fix is by going to cmd and typing in the command "bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi" But this didn't work. 
I notice that "Ubuntu" doesn't even show up as a bootable option after installing ubuntu. Is there any recommendations for this? i.e. should I try an older version of Ubuntu? Would that even work?

Thanks!
-Jacob Hempel

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer:
[adding Windows into the grub in 16.04LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/816597/partition-doesnt-show-after-formatting-failed/816695#816695)

if your Windows in /dev/sda2 change the line msdos3 with msdos2 and so on in "40_custom" file.Use "Disks" program in Ubuntu to find where the Windows is.